# Google calendar ETag not updated after modifying calendar info (name, description etc)

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client, google-client

I use Google Calendar API v3 to retrieve a user's `CalendarList`, with each `CalendarListEntry` containing basic information about the calendar such as summary (title), description etc.

The returned `CalendarListEntry` has a `etag` property, which according to Google documentation, should change whenever a calendar is modified.

But during testing, I changed my Google calendar's name, description etc, and they do not trigger any `etag` updates at all.

So how do I find out if a calendar's information (not event, but calendar's meta data such as title etc) has changed without making a full comparison against my local copy in my app?

Comment: How exactly are you getting the data? Can you share a snippet of code so I can try to reproduce? I just did a quick test on the "Try This API" by changing the color of one of my calendars and the etag changed successfully.

Comment: @iansedano I'm also using "Try this API" to test and after reading your comment, I tested it by changing the color and it indeed updated the etag. But changing name/description of the calendar still does not update the etag. If this is by design, then this Google etag thing is fairly inconsistent/useless I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This may be a bug

This issue has been reported here:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180946049

Maybe it is a bug. Go give it a ☆ to let Google know that it affects you.

#### Workaround

While the CalendarList `list` request etag does not reflect change in calendar names, the Calendar `get` request does.

> https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get

- List the calendars
- Loop through the IDs and make a simple get request for each calendar.

#### Update

Hadn't noticed that the non-universal support for etags is covered in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/version-resources#conditional_retrieval):

> Every resource has a version field that changes every time the resource changes — the etag field. Etags are a standard part of HTTP and are supported in the calendar API for two cases:
>
> - on resource modifications to ensure that there has been no other write to this resource in the meantime (conditional modification)
> - on resource retrieval to only retrieve resource data if the resource has changed (conditional retrieval)

So this is not a bug, it is "working as intended".

If you want to change this, then you would need to file a feature request!